# how to use Candlestick chart in silverlight in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I want to use financial charts in silverlight to be integrated in asp.net.

Answer (score 4):

I believe Visiblox also includes OHLC type charts, as well as candlestick.